# How can I build an APK file using MoSync Reload?

Tags: android, build, apk, reload, mosync

I tried building an application using the MoSync Reload environment.
The project does work through the web interface + android client.
Now I would like to make an Android installer file ".apk".

So my question is simple :
`How can I generate an Android "APK" file using MoSync Reload ?`

Answer (score 1):

So I took a look around and MoSync Reload can only be used for rapid development and testing.
If the point is to build an application (for any device) you have to use the MoSync SDK.